# Why does transition remove text from my labels?

Tags: d3.js, label, transition

I have a pie chart and I'm trying to transition the rotation of my labels. For some reason, when I add `transition`, the text is removed. I've created a fiddle of my problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/samselikoff/k69We/

The chart renders but without labels. On line 110, uncomment out the `setTimeout` function. After a second, the transition will work correctly.

Why does the transition without the setTimeout blow away the label values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The erring pair of lines in the code are line 65:

```
   piece.append("g").attr("class", "label").append("text").style("opacity", 0);
```

And line 93:

```
  g.selectAll(".label")
    .data(function(d) {return d;})
    .transition()
    .duration(500)
    // ...
    .select('text')
    // ...
    .style("opacity", 1)
```

You [cancel this transition on `text`](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/transition/#per-element) on line 114 by starting a new transition:

```
          g.selectAll(".label")
          .select("text")
          .transition()
          .duration(500)
          // ... (opacity is not changed here)
```

Hence, the `opacity` of the `text` stays zero. You can inspect the DOM to see that indeed the `text` elements exist (i.e. not blowen away) but just with opacity zero. This is a behavioural change between D3v2.7 and D3v3.

Now there are number of ways of correcting this depending on what was the behaviour you originally wanted. One of the ways is this: http://jsfiddle.net/zvPB6/ which *straightens* the labels in-sync with the other transitions.

If you wanted a `.delay(500)` for the `straightening`, then you'll probably have to listen to the `end` event and start a new transition in order to not delay the whole transition on all `text`s.

Comment: I did know the elements were still there, but saw that there was no `text` value. I suppose the latter transition canceled the earlier one before it set its `text` property...is that correct? And, your fiddle is exactly what I'm shooting for. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help and, yes, the cancelled transition will explain the missing `textContent` of the `text` elements.